Singular values of $A^{-1}$ where $A$ has standard normal entries
Is anything known about behavior of singular values of $A^{-1}$ where $A$ has standard normal entries?
Empirically, $k$th singular value appears to decay as $1/k$, is this well-known?

colab

The singular values of $A^{-1}$ are the reciprocals of the singular values of $A.$  At the very least, you can use that to speed up your numerical experiments.  At best, that alone might answer your question (to the extent existing literature on random matrices gives you satisfactory information).

results of this type are indeed well-known (by others, not by me :)); I'm surprised you haven't gotten an answer here, and you may have better luck over at math SE.
